# What is the best way to stub multiple class methods with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm using Ruby **3.2.2** with Rails **7.0.5**.

I'm writing a unit test some code while mocking/stubbing a utility class that uses various class methods.

It roughly looks like this:

```
class MyUtilityClass
  def self.foo
    # Does something...
  end

  def self.bar
    # Does something else...
  end
end

class MyTestTarget
  def run_foo
    MyUtilityClass.foo
  end
end
```

I want to test that when I call `run_foo` it calls `foo` but not `bar` in `MyUtilityClass`. So I need to stub both `foo` and `bar` as part of my test.

I know how to stub methods like this:

```
test 'calls foo' do
  mock_foo = Minitest::Mock.new
  mock_foo.expect :call, nil, []
  MyUtilityClass.stub :foo, mock_foo do
    t = MyTestTarget()
    t.run_foo
  end
  mock_foo.verify
end
```

What is the most elegant/best practice way to test that `bar()` was **not** called as part of this test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning at the end.

So, the ugly answer your actual question, I believe the only way with `Minitest::Mock` is to create a mock for your `:bar` and then assert that `.verify` DOES raise `MockExpectationError`.

...but the much nicer answer to your underlying question is that the awkward API and lack of features in the built-in mocking is why gems like `mocha` exist, and I'd strongly recommend it's worth switching to even if for just this one use case:

```rb
test 'calls foo not bar' do
  MyUtilityClass.expects(:foo).once
  MyUtilityClass.expects(:bar).never
  MyTestTarget.new.run_foo
end
```

#### Warning

Hopefully you know how fickle testing that something has NOT been called can be. Eg. if someone later adds a call to `bar` inside `foo` then because you're mocking `foo` in your test, then `bar` will still not be being called (in your test) even though it IS being called in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I'm aware that it's fickle to test things not being called, however I have a very very specific edge case where I want to test this to prevent a regression (basically it's ensuring that something is not called under a certain situation through the model on_update hook).

This is great and I'll give it a try, however I was wondering if there was a way to mock both foo and bar without nesting the `MyUtilityClass.stub` block?

Comment: Ah cool you're aware of the fickle thing. And re the nesting, I'm not even sure how you'd do it with nesting, you can only stub the method out with one of the mocked objects. AFAICT, you'd need to test both the "called foo" and "didn't call bar" in two separate tests, with separate mocks.